# ARM: flash memory gets erased after a few seconds automatically using stm32l0 nucleo

Tags: arm, stm32

i facing a major problem after flashing the program into the nucleo board,here i am using a stm32l053r8t6 nucleo board (compiler: keil MDK v5.0).

```
        problem: after loading any program(eg:blink problem) from keil into controller
```

board,after a few seconds the board's connection is lost (note: usb is not plugged out)meanwhile the flash memory program is also lost,therefore i have to program from the beginning on wards

kindly update if anyone understand the issue...

hope keil community response fast..

Comment: a nucleo board works like an mbed board, you simply copy the .bin file to what appears to be a flash drive.  then the debug controller stops and programs the target microcontroller and resets it.  what happened when you tried that?

Comment: isn't the program loaded into RAM only?

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the ST-Link v2 drivers or utility? If not, have a look here: http://www.st.com/web/en/catalog/tools/PF258168

This utility is used for flashing STM32 development boards with an ST-Link v2 debugger/programmer (the entire Nucleo line). Download the utility, install it, and installing it should also install the drivers for you. If it does not, you can get them here: http://www.st.com/web/en/catalog/tools/FM147/SC1887/PF260219

If programming with Keil still does not work after installing the USB driver, find the compiled binary that Keil produced, and use the utility to flash the chip with that binary.

Comment: i have already tried using st-link v2 utility,the same happen.i have tested with two similar board in my system,but when i tested with another system its working,this issue is happening only in my system..

Comment: What do you mean by system? Something else you can try is deploying a binary that you are *certain* works. Your board is supported by mBed, so you can go here: https://developer.mbed.org/platforms/ST-Nucleo-L053R8/ sign up, and create a sample blinky program. You should then be able to drag and drop the compiled .bin file to your board. If that doesn't work, update your board firmware as explained here: https://developer.mbed.org/teams/ST/wiki/Nucleo-Firmware and then try again

Comment: system means my PC,let me try your opinion,i have already installed the latest  st link utility again..

Comment: Ahh, I see. To verify that the drivers are in place, open up a command prompt, and type in "driverquery". Then, towards the bottom of the list, you must have one called "usbser" and one called "WinUSB". Also, when programming with st-link v2, use the .hex file, not the bin, if possible. I've had issues where it put the program into the wrong memory location

Comment: your idea for upgrade worked successfully,now my blink program is working,and i have also checked the driverquery also ,its also showing both the file name "usbser" and one called "WinUSB" .......but still i didn't get understand what is issue....your idea helps me a lot thanks friend.. @ Austin

Comment: Glad I could help :) The problem was most likely that either the program was not being placed at the right memory address, or that you didn't have the proper drivers installed. Please mark as answered if this resolved your issue

Comment: Answer: i have reinstalled the driver as told before is the above message ,and the issue got cleared.....

Comment: Have any of you experienced any issues after resetting or power cycling the device? In my case, the sample program works but, after power cycling, it seems like the flash memory got erased. The program doesn't work until I drag the .bin file to the drive again.